# I don't know the use colon in C

Tags: c, freebsd

I'm browsing freebsd code and i see this:

i don't understand the use of colon in C

this is an example: **u_char    ip_hl:4, ip_v:4;**

anyone have an idea?

Comment: Read about [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field).

Answer (score 5):

These colons are used to set bit fields of structure members. `u_char ip_hl:4` means `u_char ip_hl` can hold only up to `4` bits.

Answer (score 4):

This is to do with Bit fields. You can learn more about it by reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields)